# Simple PHP word generator

Tags: php, string

I'm trying to use php to create a simple script that will generate all possible word combinations.

For example when a user types in CVC. It generate all letter possible combinations of consonant vowel consonant (ex. bab, beb, bib, etc.) Or CVVC will generate words like beeb, beob, beib, etc..

Comment: Sounds a bit like homework. Can you post what you have tried so far and where you got stuck?

Comment: valid words? what language? how do you plan to determine that? the other is a trivial task.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of ways to do this. Probably the cleanest is recursion. In particular, you want to loop over all vowels (or consonants) in your main loop. For each iteration of that loop, call the function recursively with the tail (so if the input is "cvc", the tail is "vc"). In the base case, when the template string is empty, print the string.